# Header above the page scroll HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I'm doing a page with angle and I pass that the header is above the scroll of my page, any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}

.element {
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 230, 194);
}

.material-icons {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="element">
            <i class="material-icons">
            change_history
        </i>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <h3>Formulario</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and I'd like you to keep the properties that the display:sticky gives you but it's a fixed position to be able to scroll on my page, i would be very much served your help!!

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the body part of your code

Comment: I've just done it with css, bootstrap and html I haven't included code in the component

Comment: weird, I can't replicate your error

Comment: can you see the error in other navigator?

Comment: I already found the error, the question was that I was defining a body in a component, at the end in the angular index.html I defined the color to body for all components and the header is arranged very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
height: 88px;
}

.element {
display: inline-block !important;
padding: 5px;
color: rgb(255, 230, 194);
}

.material-icons {
font-size: 60px;
}
.mainbox{
 height:150px; 
 overflow-y:auto
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="element">
        <i class="material-icons">
        change_history
        </i>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <h3>Formulario</h3>
      </div>
   </div>

<div class="mainbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud               
   exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
   irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
  </header>
```